# What is the correct way of terminating firebase function with error when using async/await

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

I have a function like below

```
export const detectClient = functions.https.onRequest(async (request, response) => {
   try
   {
      const data = await foo();
      return response.status(200).send(data);
   }
   catch(err) {
      throw new functions.https.HttpsError('internal', 'error', err);
   }
}
```

The issue is when error happens firebase function doesn't terminate

If I use

```
 return response.status(500).end('error');
```

it will terminate correctly.

So I am not sure what is the correct way and if I need to use `response.status(500)` what is the usage of `throw new functions.https.HttpsError`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are confusing [error handling for callable functions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable#handle_errors) with error handling for [HTTP functions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/http-events).  The function you're showing is an HTTP type function (because it's declared with `functions.https.onRequest`), which doesn't use the error handling conventions as callable functions.  For HTTP type functions, you should explicitly send the response as you've shown in your question.